# datepicker/datetimepicker jQuery widget appearing on different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, datetimepicker

So, the scenario is that I have a webpage with two divs, one main div and a sliding div panel implemented using mmenu, which appears on a button click from the main div. And now I have a text box on the right sliding panel, on which I am trying to use the datepicker widget (also tried the datetimepicker widget - http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).
Now, the problem is that when I click on the text box and the datepicker/datetimepicker widget appears but not on top of the text box but it appears at a distance on the main div. It seems that if I have the right panel clicked and then I hover over the widget, then also the widget does not seem to show the on hover button color changes, but if i click on the main div and then hover over the datepicker widget, then all the changes expected on hover occurs. So, it seems that the datepicker widget is drawn over the main div.

I have been trying to debug this for hours now, can anyone think of any reason why this might be happening and how to make the widget appear on top of the textbox in the sliding div and not on the main div.

Comment: What do you have so far codewise. Show it to us.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML and Javascript? I wonder if you have more than one item with the same ID

Comment: Sorry, code is proprietary, don't think I can share. I posted this question hoping, either someone else has seen something like this before and can point me in the right direction or can suggest some common causes of this sort of errors. I am not an expert at JS or jQuery so I might have messed something up.

@JamesKing I am pretty sure there is not an ID conflict with the ID of the textbox on which the datepicker is applied, as I tried changing it around as well, and it didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion, though!